# Are quasi-components open?

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra

I never encountered a confirming answer on the question in the title so have great distrust in my own reasoning below.

That made me decide to ask it as a question here.

---

Let $X$ be a topological space with $x\in X$.

Let $\mathsf{CO}\left(X\right)$ denote the collection of clopen subsets
of $X$.

Equipped with $\cap,\cup$ and complement $\mathsf{CO}\left(X\right)$
can be recognized as a Boolean algebra.

Let $u_{x}=\left\{ C\in\mathsf{CO}\left(X\right)\mid x\in C\right\} $.

Then $u_{x}$ can be recognized as an ultrafilter of Boolean algebra
$\mathsf{CO}\left(X\right)$.

We have $x\in\bigcap u_{x}$ so that $\bigcap u_{x}\neq\varnothing$.

An ultrafilter that is not free must be a principal filter generated by
an atom, so some atom $A\in\mathsf{CO}\left(X\right)$ must exist
with $u_{x}=\left\{ C\in\mathsf{CO}\left(X\right)\mid A\subseteq C\right\} $.

Then $\bigcap u_{x}=A\in\mathsf{CO}\left(X\right)$ showing that $\bigcap u_{x}$
is an open set.

But $\bigcap u_{x}$ can also be recognized as the quasi-component represented
by element $x$.

Proved is now that quasi-components are open sets.

---

I must have made a mistake somewhere, I think, and will be thankful if you could point out what I did wrong.

Comment: This is assuming that the Boolean algebra is complete, which is not obvious to me.

Comment: @nbritten where exactly do I make that assumption implicitly? If I really do that then you are right. This Boolean algebra is not necessarily complete.

Comment: When you assume that $\bigcap u_x\in \mathsf{CO}(X)$. All you have is that there is some clopen set generating the filter, but I don't see that it needs to be $\bigcap u_x$.

Comment: @nbritten Is the conclusion that $\bigcap u_x=A$ a wrong statement then?

Comment: Right, there exists some $A\in\mathsf{CO}(X)$ generating the ultrafilter. Certainly $\bigcap u_x\subseteq A$ but I don't see the other inclusion.

Comment: There need not be atoms at all in $\mathrm{CO}(X)$ so why would an ultrafilter be generated by one?

Comment: Consider $\mathrm{CO}(X)$  for $X=\{0,1\}^\omega$ the Cantor set; all quasi-components are singletons, so none are open.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, I am convinced I am wrong. My reasoning: If $0$ is not its greatest lower bound then it must have another lower bound $p\neq0$. Then it must be contained in proper filter $\uparrow p$ and by maximality it must equalize $\uparrow p$. Then it can be proved that $p$ is an atom. What is wrong with this?

Comment: You're assuming there **is** a glb. There need not be.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $0$ is a lower bound of the ultrafilter. If it is unique in being a lower bound then by definition $0$ is the greatest lower bound of it. If it is not unique in being a lower bound then there must be another lower bound, ...et cetera (see former comment). So where in my reasoning do I really *assume* the existence of a greatest lower bound? I cannot find it.

Comment: Precisely, $\emptyset$ could be the glb and then you have nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined an ultrafilter in a Boolean algebra, agreed. But $\bigcap u_x$ (or really $\bigwedge u_x$) is not defined in that BA necessarily. Having it non-empty *as sets* means little. Assuming the intersection is clopen is saying that $\mathrm{CO}(X)$ is complete; you only have $\emptyset=0$ as a lower bound for $u_x$ in $\mathrm{CO}(X)$, so if the inf existed it could well be $\emptyset$ too. Claiming $u_x$ is not free in the BA is already positing the existence of a clopen $A\neq \emptyset$ as a lowerbound, begging the question.

Also, $\mathrm{CO}(X)$ could very well be atomless, so the "generated by an atom" statement makes no sense.